# convert following iterative code to recursive Python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

6174 is known as Kaprekar's constant[1][2][3] after the Indian mathematician D. R. Kaprekar. This number is notable for the following property:

Take any four-digit number, using at least two different digits. (Leading zeros are allowed.)
Arrange the digits in descending and then in ascending order to get two four-digit numbers, adding leading zeros if necessary.
Subtract the smaller number from the bigger number.
Go back to step 2.

Dattaraya Ramchandra Kaprekar

```
number="0011" 

print(" helo world,  lets do this: " , number)
i = 0
while number != "6174":
 sortedS = sorted(number)                            
 String[] sortedString = array[4] av strangen number
 reversed = sorted(number, reverse=True)            
 sortedIntMin = int(sortedS[0]+sortedS[1]+sortedS[2]+sortedS[3])
 reversedIntMax = int(reversed[0]+reversed[1]+reversed[2]+reversed[3])  
 i += 1
 number = str(reversedIntMax - sortedIntMin)                                           
 reversedIntMax - sortedIntMin
 print("det behovdes " , i , "iterationer for processen")
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt

```
def Kaprekar(number, i):
if number == 6174:
    return
elif number != 6174:
    sortedString = sorted(number)
    reversedString = sorted(number, reverse=True)
    sortedIntMin = int(sortedString[0]+sortedString[1]+sortedString[2]+sortedString[3])
    reversedIntMax = int(reversedString[0]+reversedString[1]+reversedString[2]+reversedString[3])
    num = reversedIntMax - sortedIntMin
    print("processen kors", num )
    return 1 + Kaprekar(str(num), i)

print(" helo world,  lets do this: ")
print("det behovdes " , Kaprekar("1547", 0) , "iterationer for processen")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are three things that are wrong: -

1. You don't need i. remove it from function definition.
2. The variable you are passing is a string and you are comparing it with an integer, convert it to a string while comparing.
3. You need to return 1 when number='6174', while you are returning None.
4. Also, it can be done a bit clearer if list is joined after sorted and it can be directly converted to integer, (thanks endzior for the edit)

   try this : -

   ```
   def Kaprekar(number):
       if number == '6174':
           return 1
       elif number != '6174':
           sortedString = ''.join(sorted(number))
           reversedString = ''.join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
           sortedIntMin = int(sortedString)
           reversedIntMax = int(reversedString)
           num = reversedIntMax - sortedIntMin
           print("processen kors", num )
           return  1 + Kaprekar(str(num))

   print(" helo world,  lets do this: ")
   print("det behovdes " , Kaprekar("1547") , "iterationer for processen")
   ```

Comment: To add to this answer, you don't need to be calling each character of the string to convert it to int, if every character of a given string is a digit you can just call `int(sortedString)` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`number` is a string, so in the first 2 if statements :

```
if number == '6174':
    return 1
else:
```

And as in another answer `i` variable is not needed here.